# get all data count from relationship | Laravel

Tags: laravel, command

i use laravel:command for function, which is i need to know how many reviews been given to my products, i will capture my database example below:

[Product fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUtdo.png)

[Reviews fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmCzI.png)

i've already declare the relationship which is:

App\Models\Product :

```
public function rev()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Reviews::class, 'product_id', 'id');
    }
```

App\Models\Review :

```
public function prod()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Products::class, 'product_id','id');
    }
```

and this is my command for the function:

```
protected $signature = 'review:product {product_id}';
public function handle()
{
    $id = $this->arguments('product_id');
    $products = Products::with('rev')->whereId($id)->get();

    foreach ($products as $key => $value) {
        $rating = $value->rev->rating;
    }

    dd($products);
}
```

after i run my command it returns this error
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUTGB.png)

what i'm expecting is i could get the whole rating of specific id

Comment: Welcome to SO ... do you just want a count of how many reviews a product has? or does the rating matter?

Answer (score 0):

You did not declare the variable $rating prior to using it.

But there is a much easier approach to your problem, since youve already setup the relationships.

```
public function handle()
{
    $id = $this->arguments('product_id');
    
    $products = Products::find($id);

    $ratings = $products->rev->pluck('rating');

    dd($ratings);
}
```

Comment: i've tried this, and returning " Property [rev] does not exist on this collection instance." this error

Answer (score 0):

Because of `product` can have many `revs`, so you can use loop for this

```
foreach ($value->rev as $item) {
  $val = $item->rating;
}
```

Comment: should i put this code, inside my foreach?

Answer (score 0):

if you are expecting to sum up all rating for particular product id, then you should declare initial number for variable `$rating` before `foreach`, then sum up with `+=` operator :

```
public function handle(){
    $id = $this->arguments('product_id');
    $products = Products::with('rev')->whereId($id)->get();

    $rating = 0;
    foreach ($products as $key => $value) {
        $rating += $value->rev->rating;
    }

    dd($rating);
}
```